# editing a global variable

Tags: android, text, global-variables

Hi im new to android and I have a program that has a global variable define and it works, so I can set it and get it in every activity, BUT it dosnt like to be changed in an on click listener. I made it so on the screen there is an edittext and when someone presses a button I want the edittext text to be put into the global variable. here is my code:

```
Button SiteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SiteButton);
    SiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        TextView textviewS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SiteIdT);
        EditText edittextS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SiteIdE);
        TextView textviewB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BusIdT);
        EditText edittextB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BusIdE);
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textviewS.setText(edittextS.getText());
            ((Global) this.getApplication()).setgSiteId(textviewS.getText().toString());
            textviewB.setText(edittextB.getText()); 
            ((Global) this.getApplication()).setgVehicleId(textviewB.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

but the `getApplication()` part is showing an error. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to your activity `this`, since `View.OnClickListener` doesn't have such a method:

```
// Bad code! read below
((Global) MyActivityClassName.this.getApplication()).setgSiteId(textviewS.getText().toString());
textviewB.setText(edittextB.getText()); 
((Global) MyActivityClassName.this.getApplication()).setgVehicleId(textviewB.getText().toString());
```

By the way, how do you cast the return from `getApplication()` to `Global`? You will get a class cast exception there.